# How to get a pointer to private member function to be passed to a friend in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

The original requirement is that I need all the member function invocations for all my classes happen through a proxy class (Fortress).

Let's say I have a class 'A'. My solution was to make all the member functions in 'A', private and make 'Fortress' friend of 'A'. Now only 'Fortress' can call 'A' member functions.

The problem is how can I ask 'Fortress' to invoke a given function. I'm not comfortable using a map based solution because I need the highest performance I can get through 'Fortress'.

A perfect solution for me would be, any outside class (let's say 'B') can get a pointer to a member function in 'A'. But 'B' cannot call that function directly because it's private. 'B' can bind the arguments and pass that function to 'Fortress' to be called. However, this is not possible because I cannot even create the pointer inside 'B' because the function is private.

Example code of the path I'm directed to given below. Thanks in advance for anyone who can give me any insight.

```c
class Fortress;

class A{
public:
    explicit A(std::string  name): m_name(std::move(name)){}

private:
    friend Fortress;
    void setName(const std::string& name) {m_name  = name;}
    std::string getName() { return m_name;};

    std::string m_name;
};

class Fortress{
public:
    template <typename R, typename F>
    R call(F f){
        return static_cast<R>(f());
    }

    template <typename T>
    void call(T t){
        t();
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = A("Whatever");

    auto fortress = Fortress();

    fortress.call(std::bind(&A::setName, &a, "Hello"));

    std::cout << fortress.call<std::string>(std::bind(&A::getName, &a)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a proxy call and, at the same time request the highest performance?

Comment: The reason is that 'Fortress' need to moderate the number of calls happen to 'A', as an example. So the proxy indirection I have to have. But I'm all ears for any other solutions.

Comment: The simplest implementation is to build in that moderation in A itself, using public member functions that would verify what you want before calling the private ones.

Comment: Your design is fully broken in my mind! If you have something private, you definitely say that you don't want access from the outside world. Even if you need something like a "moderator", the caller of the moderator also wants with or without the moderator, access to the private methods. So how can it be private? Or do you want moderate calls from "inside A" to its own methods? Sounds all broken for me! So please give us an idea how A methods are called without moderator to see what is the use case. All sounds like an XY problem

Comment: Making functions in 'A' private, is actually a bad side effect. My requirement is that only 'Fortress' can access any member functions of 'A'. Anyone else have to ask 'Fortress' to call the functions in 'A'.

Comment: Access control applies to the names, not the functions. Anyone can call a private function through a pointer, but only the class and its friends can create such a pointer.

Comment: Seems my only option is a message based architecture.